# What happens when __aenter__() fails using 'async with'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, semantics, aiohttp

The [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with) mentions that:

```
async with EXPR as VAR:
    BLOCK
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
mgr = (EXPR)
aexit = type(mgr).__aexit__
aenter = type(mgr).__aenter__

VAR = await aenter(mgr)
try:
    BLOCK
except:
    if not await aexit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
        raise
else:
    await aexit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

However, `VAR = await aenter(mgr)` is not in the `try` block so I am wondering if `__aenter__()` is allowed to fail.

For example, in this this `aiohttp` snippet (taken from [*Getting Started*](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/#client-example)):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('http://python.org') as response:

            print("Status:", response.status)
            print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

            html = await response.text()
            print("Body:", html[:15], "...")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

`session.get('http://python.org')` could fail and `__aexit__()` would not be called to close the context.

Comment: *and `__aexit__()` would not be called to close the context.* - what context are you referring to? The session will be closed because the exception happened in the body of the outer `async with`. If you mean `response`, there is nothing to close because `session.get(...)` never finished running, it raised an exception instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `__aenter__` fails, `__aexit__` is indeed not run. Any required cleanup is `__aenter__`'s responsibility in this case.

`__aenter__` has more information about how far it got and what did or did not get successfully initialized, so having `__aenter__` handle this is more convenient than expecting `__aexit__` to handle cleaning up arbitrary partially-entered context manager states.

(This is exactly the same for normal, non-async context managers.)